# Как правильно нарисовать равноудаленные точки круга от центра?

Tags: java, android, canvas, рисование

Задача состоит в том, чтобы нарисовать 7 равноудаленных точек от центра круга. Но получается немного криво. Помогите подкорректировать код (см. ниже):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    setUpDrawingArea();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float centerX = width / 2;
    float centerY = height / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < colours.size(); i++) {
        paint.setColor(colours.get(i));
        float stat = stats.get(i) / 100f;
        percent = (width * 1f) * stat;
        int arcLeft = 50;
        int arcTop = 50;
        int arcRight = right - 50;
        int arcBottom = bottom - 50;
        float statRadius = arcLeft + ((1 - stat) * (arcRight / 2.2f));
        canvas.drawArc(arcLeft + statRadius, arcTop + statRadius, arcRight - statRadius, arcBottom - statRadius, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint);
        startAngle += sweepAngle;
    }

    startAngle = 0;
    float degree;

    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        degree = startAngle + (sweepAngle / 2);
        float newX = centerX + (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (width / 2.25f));
        float newY = centerY + (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (width / 2.25f));
        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), icons[i]);
        int iconWidth = width / 6;
        int iconHeight = height / 6;
        resizedIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, iconWidth, iconHeight, false);
        resizedIcon = rotateBitmap(resizedIcon, degree - 270);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedIcon, newX - (iconWidth / 2f), newY - (iconHeight / 2f), paint);
        startAngle += sweepAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно что есть что. Добавьте комментариев  по переменным и скрин того, что получаете сейчас. Если еще и нарисуете что хотите получить - вообще прекрасно будет

Comment: Начну с критики: много грязной работы в `onDraw` - этот метод должен только рисовать объекты на холсте, а не загружать их из ресурсов и по два раза преобразовывать. По задаче: не ломая зубы о тригонометрию я бы сделал проще - когда вы рисуете в реале на бумаге, то вы поворачиваете сам лист бумаги, а не извращаетесь рисуя всё вверх ногами и лёжа. Здесь можно так же - поворачивать холст, а картинки рисовать на одном и том же месте. В этом поможет метод [`Canvas.rotate(degrees, cx, cy)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: Вообщем задача заключается в следующем если описать поподробнее: имеется 7 иконок круглой формы. Нужно их закрепить равноудаленно от центра. Должно выглядеть как будто 7 спутников вокруг одной точки, находящиеся на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга.